# Can I stylize the current closed-fold line? If yes, how?

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, highlight, folding

I like to have the current line highlighted (in terminal vim), but not as a punch in my eye, so what I have is this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
au ColorScheme *
  \ hi CursorLine ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE cterm=bold |
  " ... other stuff
```

How can I do the same for the when the current line represents a closed fold?

I've searched `:help highlight-groups` for `fold` case insensitive, but I've only found `Folded`, `FoldColumn`, and `CursorLineFold`, and the last one seemed promising, given its naming similar to `CursorLine`, but apparently it's not so.

Comment: `Folded` is for the closed fold. I don't think there is a way to style a cursorline over a folded.

Comment: `Folded` highlights closed folds. `FoldColumn` and `CursorLineFold` highlight the folding indicators in margin; the latter applies to the indicator of the current line, except when it’s a closed fold, apparently. There is apparently no way of styling a closed fold when you have your cursor on it, be it the line itself or the stuff in margin.